# Dynamics CRM Early Bound Generator Error (XRMToolBox)

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, early-binding, xrmtoolbox

We are using XrmToolBox to support early bound (with early bound generattor).

From one day to the other the early bound generator doesn't work anymore.

I got this log from the ui. What's the problem or where can I find the entire log?

```
CrmSvcUtil Error: 2 : Exiting program with exit code 2 due to exception : Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault
CrmSvcUtil Error: 2 : ===== DETAIL ======
CrmSvcUtil Error: 2 : Source    : mscorlib
Method  : HandleReturnMessage
Date    : 15:04:43
Time    : 08.08.2017
Error   : An error occurred. Contact a system administrator or refer to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK troubleshooting guide.
Stack Trace : Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.ExecuteCore(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.SdkMetadataProviderService.RetrieveSdkRequests(IOrganizationService service)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.SdkMetadataProviderService.LoadMetadata()
   at DLaB.CrmSvcUtilExtensions.BaseMetadataProviderService.LoadMetadataInternal()
   at DLaB.CrmSvcUtilExtensions.Entity.MetadataProviderService.LoadMetadataInternal()
   at DLaB.CrmSvcUtilExtensions.BaseMetadataProviderService.LoadMetadata()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.CrmSvcUtil.Run()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.CrmSvcUtil.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Obviously something must have been changed. The stack trace shows that the exception is raised when querying metadata on the CRM organization service. Could the url have been changed? You can try intercepting the traffic using Fiddler; it may give you more details on the error.

Comment: Is this an on-prem?  Any chance you're using an old version of the tool?

Comment: Thanks for your responses.
We are using Dynamics 365.
We also tried with the new early bound generator version.
1 solution has been added (Ribbon Workbench) and 1 Extension (Application Ribbons) to Contact Entity.

Comment: Fiddler had a problem at this point:

`&lt;fetch distinct='true' version='1.0'&gt;
                &lt;entity name='sdkmessage'&gt;
                               &lt;attribute name=[some more attributes...]
                               &lt;link-entity name='sdkmessagepair' alias='sdkmessagepair' to='sdkmessageid' from='sdkmessageid' link-type='inner'&gt;...
`

Comment: We found the solution:
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/120680 

Thanks!